# DatePicker is fetching from access db using mm/dd/yyyy format but I want dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Transactions] WHERE [TransDate] =  #" & Format(StartDatePicker.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy"), myConnection)
```

When I pick a date with a day value greater than 12 it works normally using dd/mm/yyyy format, but when I pick day below 12, it uses mm/dd/yyy format.

I am using vb.net and ms access.

Comment: A `DateTime` does do not have a format - formats are for how we show them to users or how we describe the layout for parsing.  Save the Date as a Date and all will be well.  Use SQL Parameters to be sure it is passed as Date

Comment: Gah! This is **NOT** Sql injection safe code. Google parameterized queries before you do _anything_ else.

Answer (score 1):

Plutonix has already explained that a date is a date, format is for humans only. Here is revised version of your code that would work regardless of culture:

```
Dim sql As string = <sql>SELECT * FROM [Transactions] 
  WHERE [TransDate] >= @tStart and [TransDate] < @tEnd
</sql>.Value
Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myConnection)

Dim start = StartDatePicker.Value.Date
Dim end = StartDatePicker.Value.Date.AddDays(1)

da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tStart", start)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tEnd", end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where the problem was. it was confusing to read 08/12/2016 from the database. it was read as mm/dd/yyyy while 15/12/16 was read as dd/MM/yyyy. I set the datepicker to yyyy/MM/dd. Many Thanks for the help

Comment: While this may have fixed the immediate problem, parameter queries solve numerous problems, compared to string-building. Look how there is no need to get involved with formats at all in Cetin Basoz' code. And no doubt someone will be along shortly to warn you about SQL injection.

Comment: This is wallpapering over the real issue, at best.  If your database is sensitive to date formats, I suspect they are not being stored as dates, but as text.  **Dont do that**.  DateTime and strings are 2 different things and *as you have already discovered* dates stored as strings act wonky.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong format for your string expression of the date value in SQL. Thus:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Transactions] WHERE [TransDate] = #" & Format(StartDatePicker.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd"), myConnection)
```

Note please, that format has nothing to do with the format you wish to use for display of the dates.

Also, while this will work, absorb the comments on using more clever methods.